# How can I let the Kotlin compiler know I already checked for null inside a function?

Tags: kotlin

Basically I have a function that does some stuff but specifically it checks if two values I'm passing are null. This function is called from various places to make sure those two values are not null. Kotlin is complaining later that I'm not checking for null. Is there a way I can do this so that Kotlin already knows that I am checking for `null` without using `!!`?

Here is a simple example:

```
private fun stuff() {
    var possibleNull: String? = "test"
    if (testNull(possibleNull)) {
        mustPassNonNull(possibleNull)
    }
}

private fun mustPassNonNull(possibleNull: String) {
    //use value that isn't null
}

private fun testNull(possibleNull: String?): Boolean {
    return possibleNull != null
}
```

Basically `testNull` is only `true` if `possibleNull` is not `null` and that check is on an `if` right before calling `mustPassNonNull` so can I let Kotlin know I'm already checking that? without using `!!` of course.

Thanks.

Comment: You could make testNull take a lambda, which gets executed if `possibleNull` is not null, and the not-null version of `possibleNull` is passed as a parameter. But in general the kotlin compiler can't infer across multiple functions like this.

Comment: You can also do stuff like `possibleNull?.let { notNull -> TODO() }`

Comment: Yes, ?.let{} is a very common Kotlin idiom for this.

Comment: The example isn't very good I guess, inside `testNull` in my real code I'm doing more than checking for `null` but the example still applies since the thing the compiler complains about is the `null` check. I can just check again I guess.

Comment: @PiRocks the lambda idea is interesting, I'll see if I can modify my code that way.

Comment: It'd help if you gave more information on just what checks you're trying to do besides null. The beauty of `?.let{}` is that it captures the variable you're questioning so even if some other part of the program asynchronously changes the variable, it doesn't matter because what's captured won't change. Maybe that's good enough for your purposes but we really can't help without more information.

Comment: It isn't just that it does more stuff inside the method but also that the method gets called from a couple of other places and I want to make sure that logic is always the same from all those places. I probably need to rework what it is doing to do it that way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible with the use of *contracts*. Currently in experimental in Kotlin 1.3.

> It is possible to declare contracts for your own functions, but this feature is experimental, as the current syntax is in a state of early prototype and will most probably be changed. Also, please note, that currently the Kotlin compiler does not verify contracts, so it's a programmer's responsibility to write correct and sound contracts. -kotlinlang.org

```
@ExperimentalContracts
fun stuff() {
   var possibleNull: String? = "test"
   if (testNull(possibleNull)) {
      mustPassNonNull(possibleNull)
   }
}

fun mustPassNonNull(possibleNull: String) {
   //use value that isn't null
}

@ExperimentalContracts
fun testNull(possibleNull: String?): Boolean {
   contract{
      returns(true) implies (possibleNull is String)
   }

   return possibleNull != null
}
```

Articles I referenced:

- https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew13.html
- https://blog.kotlin-academy.com/understanding-kotlin-contracts-f255ded41ef2

Comment: While it would definitely work, it worth noting that those are experimental features and may be changed or removed in the future (and warning will remind you about it). Also `contract` doesn't have double checks from the compiler, and will trust you even if you will declare invalid "implications".

Comment: Also, `possibleNull is String` maybe should be replaced with `possibleNull != null` to remove "hard link" to the type, in case if this function will be used for different type of as a generic. `!= null` will still work, `is String` will require refactoring.

Comment: Worked perfect but I'll have to wait until it isn't experimental since I need it on production. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a simple `let` situation

```
private fun stuff() {
    var possibleNull: String? = "test"
    possibleNull?.let { mustPassNonNull(it) }
}
```

This way mustPassNonNull will know that it isn't null :)

Also, if you need to do more than just check for nullability you could do:

```
possibleNull
    ?.takeIf { /* it's not null here anymore, add any checks you need */}
    ?.let { /* both non-null and checked for whatever you need */}
```